# "Obvious" equality from elementary measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

I started to learn measure theory and yesterday when I was watching lecture I asked myself the following question:

> Suppose $S$ is semiring of sets, i.e. $S$ is a collection of sets with
>   the following 3 properties:
>
> 1. $\varnothing\in S$.
> 2. If $A,B\in S$ then $A\cap B\in S$.
> 3. If $A,A_1\in S$ and $A_1\subset A$ then $\exists$ finitely many disjoint sets $A_2,\dots,A_n\in S$ such that $A=\sqcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i$.

Let $m:S\to [0,\infty)$ be a $\sigma$-additive measure on $S$. And suppose that $$B=\bigsqcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigsqcup_{l=1}^{l_n}D_{n,l},$$ where $B,D_{n,l}\in S$ for all $n,l$. And my professor claimed that from $\sigma$-additivie of $m$ it follows that $$m(B)=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum \limits_{l=1}^{l_n}m(D_{n,l}).$$

But it was not so clear to me why it immediately follows from $\sigma$-additivity of $m$ because we have double disjoint union. But I spent sometime and I guess that I know how to prove it rigorously .

**Proof:** For each $n\geq 1$, let $K_n=\{(n,l): 1\leq l\leq l_n\}$ and $K=\cup _{n=1}^{\infty} K_n$. Since $K$ is countable then $\exists \sigma:K\to \mathbb{N}$ which is a bijection. For each suitable pair $(n,l)$ we put $E_{\sigma(n,l)}=D_{n,l}$. Then it's easy to show that $$B=\bigsqcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigsqcup_{l=1}^{l_n}D_{n,l}=\bigsqcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k.$$ Then from $\sigma$-additivity of $m$ it follows that $m(B)=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}m(E_k)$. In particular, the last series converges because $m(B)<\infty$ then any new series with permuted terms still converges and have the same sum.

Let's construct the following map $\rho:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$. If $x\in \mathbb{N}$ and $l_1+\dots+l_k<x\leq l_1+\dots+l_{k+1}$ for some $k\geq 1$ then I'll define $\rho(x):=\sigma(k+1,t)$ where $t=x-(l_1+\dots+l_k)$ and if $1\leq x\leq l_1$ then $\rho(x):=\sigma(1,x)$.

It is quite easy to check that $\rho$ gives us bijection. Then as I noted above $m(B)=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}m(E_{\rho(k)})$ and also we know that in convergent series if I put parenthesis then the new series still converges and have the same sum. If I put parenthesis in the first $l_1$ terms and then $l_2$ terms and so on then I'll get $$m(B)=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum \limits_{l=1}^{l_n}m(D_{n,l}).$$

So I would be very grateful for any comments and checking my proof! Sorry maybe this is a stupid question but I wanted to prove it.

Comment: I don't follow the notation, does that mean that the $D_{n,l}$ are pairwise disjoint?

Comment: @copper.hat, yeah exactly!

Comment: @copper.hat, I do not think so because $E_n$ may not be an element of semiring $S$ and $m(E_n)$ is not defined. Right?

Comment: You are correct. Let me think a little more.

Comment: @copper.hat, but is my proof correct? you think it is a bit complicated?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm looking for something simpler first.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really slow tonight. Just order the sets as in $D_{1,1},...,D_{1,l_1},D_{2,1},...,D_{2,l_2},...$ then the result follows from $\sigma$ additivity on $S$. Since all the terms are $\ge$ you don't need to worry about reordering (either the sum is $\infty$ or they are absolutely convergent).

Comment: So basically, the first paragraph after **Proof:** is sufficient in my mind.

Comment: I deleted my incorrect statement above.

Comment: Note that even if the $l_n$ were $\infty$ the result still holds because $\mathbb{N}^2$ is still countable.

Comment: @copper.hat, but anyway could you take at my proof? I really spent some time on it. I was wondering about its correctness

Comment: It is correct. I think it is a bit verbose, but that depends on your intended audience. For me your first paragraph was sufficient. The $\sigma$ that you computed is the same as the informal ordering in my 'slow' comment above.

Comment: @copper.hat, I am a bit confused, soryy you meant $\sigma$ or $\rho$?

Comment: $\rho$. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat, Is it possible to apply this to my question? If $a_{n,k}\geq 0$ and $\phi:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}^2$ is bijection then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{n,k}=\sum \limits_{p=1}^{\infty}a_{\phi(p)}$. I guess it should work and I proved this equality but cannot apply. Maybe you know?

Comment: Sure, just let $a_{n,k} = 0$ for $k \ge l_n$.

Comment: @copper.hat, i know this. I am failing to write it clearly. Could you help me please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are having difficulty with? Everything you have written is correct?

Comment: Basically if $a_k \ge 0$, you can sum it anyway you want. This is the essence of Tonelli's theorem.

Comment: I will think on this tomorrow. Probably i am a bit tired. But i have soent some time and was able to show this equality which seems to me nice :)

Comment: @copper.hat, Great! I got it :) sorry for this stupid question. It was important why my professor have done it in this way. Am i right that the equality which i provided proves it much easier than my original post?

Comment: I think so. ${}{}$